# Unexpected endless byte for loop

Tags: java, types, for-loop, byte, infinite-loop

I have the following loop:

```
for (byte i = 0 ; i < 128; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + 1 + " " + name);
}
```

When I execute my programm it prints all numbers from -128 to 127 in an infinite loop.  Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you mean it 'seems to be endless'?

Comment: @Suresh S: You wrote "byte can hold only up to 127 bits", which is indeed a lot of bits for a byte to have ;-).

Comment: Numeric types in Java are great example of leaky abstraction.

Comment: This would make a great question for a CS exam on data types

Answer (score 79, accepted):

byte is a 1-byte type so can vary between -128...127, so condition i < 128 is always true. When you add 1 to 127 it overflows and becomes -128 and so on in a (infinite) loop...

Comment: @piermesons, frankly I agree with you - 29 votes may be too much for this answer, but that's just how SO works...

Comment: @piemesons: There are worse injustices in the world; such voting is a known issue and inevitable with this type of crowd-sourcing.  Plenty of discussion about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  (FWIW, it is a good answer. ;)

Comment: so what? 29 people didn't know this, and they become enlightened by this answer. good for them.

Comment: I didn't know this (I even thought a byte went from 0 to 256!!), so I do think the answer deserves 37 upvotes.

Comment: @Coronatus, even an unsigned integer byte only ranges 0–255. Maybe you're thinking of the knob that goes to 11?

Comment: I'd say although this is a basic concept, it's easily missed, especially by less experienced programmers, and this answer is a nice and concise explanation.

Answer (score 20):

After 127, when it increments, it will become -128, so your condition won't match  .

> **byte**: The `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of `-128` and a maximum value of `127` (inclusive). The `byte` data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of `int` where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

---

It will work like this:

```
0, 1, 2, ..., 126, 127, -128, -127, ...
```

as 8 bits can represent a signed number up to 127.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for the primitive data types.

---

**Picture says more than words**
[image]

Comment: 126,127,-128,-127,... You missed one.

Answer (score 11):

Because bytes are signed in Java so they will *always* be less than 128.

Why Java chose signed bytes is a mystery from the depths of time. I've never been able to understand why they corrupted a perfectly good unsigned data type :-)

Try this instead:

```
for (byte i = 0 ; i >= 0; ++i ) {
```

or, better yet:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 128; ++i ) {
```

Comment: the only reason I can think of is for consistency, all the other integral types are signed, so if `byte` were to be unsigned, then it will be the odd one out.

Comment: Although the Common Type System in .NET has a similar limitation to signed types, if I recall correctly.

Comment: is it me or is your second snippet equal to what the op posted?

Comment: @fortran, it's just you :-) That's an `int`, which won't wrap around at 128 like the `byte` would.

Comment: He, he, true, I didn't notice the type change while visually scanning the loop structure :-)

Answer (score 7):

because when i == 127 and and you executes i++ it overflows to -128.

Answer (score 6):

The type byte has a range of -128..127. So `i` is always less than 128.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so the reason behind this has been answered already, but in case you were interested in some background:

A `bit` is the smallest unit of storage which the computer can recognize (n.b. not the smallest number). A bit is either a `0` or a `1`.

A `byte` is an 8 bit data type, meaning it is composed of 8 bit strings such as `10101010` or `0001110`. Using simple combinatorics, we know that there are `2^8 = 256` possible combinations of bytes.

If we wanted to only represent positive numbers, we could do a straight conversion from base 2 to base 10. The way that works is, for a bit string `b7b6b5b4b3b2b1b0` the number in decimal is `dec = sum from n=0 to 7 of (bn * 2^n)`.

By only representing positive numbers ( an `unsigned byte`) we can represent 256 possible numbers in the range `0` to `255` inclusive.

The problem comes in when we want to represent signed data. A naive approach (n.b. this is for background, not the way java does it) is to take the left most bit and make it the sign bit where `1` is negative and `0` is positive. So for example `00010110` would be `21` and `10010110` would be `-21`.

There are two major problems with such a system. The first is that `00000000` is `0` and `10000000` is `-0`, but as everyone knows, there is no `-0` that is somehow different from `0`, but such a system allows for the number and `0 ≠ -0`. The second problem is that, due to representing two zeroes, the system only allows for representing numbers from `-127` to `127`, a range of only `254` (`2` less than before).

A much better system (and the one which most systems use) is called [Two's Compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement). In Two's Compliment, the positive numbers are represented with their normal bit string where the leftmost bit is 0. Negative numbers are represented with the left most bit as a 1 and then calculating the two's compliment for that number (from whence the system gets its name)

Although mathematically it is a slightly more complex process, because we are dealing with the number `2` there are some short cuts. Essentially, you can take the positive version and (from right to left) take all zeroes until you hit a 1. Copy those zeroes and one, then take the `NOT` of the rest of the bits. So for example, to get `-21`, positive `21` is `00010110` we take the `10` and not the rest to get `11101010`, the two's compliment representation of `-21`.

Two's Compliment is a much more difficult system to grasp, but it avoids the previously stated problems, and for an n-bit number can represent all digits from `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1)-1` which for our byte means `-128` to `127` (hence the problem in this question)

A couple of notes:
 - This is for integer representation only. Real number representation is another system entirely (if there is a request for it, I'm sure we could make a number representation CW post)
 - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) has a couple more number representation systems if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Best is if you do

```
for (byte i = 0 ; i < Byte.MAX_VALUE; i++ ) {
  System.out.println( i + 1 + " " + name );
}
```

Comment: Best if you want to count from 0 to 126, that is :-)

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
        for (byte i = 0 ; i<128; ++i ) {
        if(i==-128)
            break;
        System.out.println( i + 1 + " " + "name" );
    }
```

Comment: -1, because of two problems: 1: That will not work (overflow - goes to -128 without going through 128) 2: Even without the overflow, the `if (i==128)` condition block would never be executed - if it was, it would mean that the `for` loop could be entered even when its conditional for entry was false.

Comment: @jhominal Yes it wont work, sorry about that. My initial answer was if(i==-128), later edited it to i==128. My bad. Have changed it back. Now it should work.:)

Comment: Why not replace the `for` loop with `for (byte i = 0; i<128 && i!=-128; ++i)`? That would get rid of the `break` statement.

Comment: simpler, but tricky (bad): `for (byte i = 0; i != (byte) 128; ++i) {`

Comment: Also simpler: `for (byte i = 0; i >= 0; ++i) {`

Comment: I think this needs to be golfed.