# Set greater than 127 int byte variable in java

Tags: java, casting, byte

I write the following sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
      byte number_1 =  127;
      byte number_2 =  (byte) 128;
      System.out.println("number_1 = " + number_1);
      System.out.println("number_2 = " + number_2);
}
```

I get the following result in output:

```
number_1 = 127
number_2 = -128
```

I know range of a `byte` data type( `-128` to `127`).
Is my sample is correct? What happened? Is there a two's complement operation? I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: That's 2's complement.  A `byte` is 8 bits, from 00000000 to 11111111.  Since a `byte` is signed, any value larger than 01111111 (ie, any value with the high-order bit set to 1) will be considered to be negative.

Answer (score 12):

Because one byte can hold upto -128 to 127 only, This is expected behavior of overflow

Check with [this loop](http://ideone.com/lJoDa)

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < 258 ; index ++ ){
  System.out.println((byte)index);
}
```

### [image: number line]

**Also See**

- [Endless for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975826/endless-for-loop/)
- [Nice comic illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn8c1.png)

Comment: Thank for your answer but I know range of a `byte` data type, I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: @MJM its not clear what you dn't understand. Think of a clock, the hour after 12 (the last) is 1 (the first) and the hour before 1 (the first) is 12 (the last)

Comment: @Peter nice example, MJM check the updated answer its simple overflow

Comment: @PeterLawrey your example is very nice.

Comment: @MJM A byte can only keep the lowest 8-bits of the result. This is what causes underflows (wrapping from negative to positive) and overflows (wrapping from positive to negative) because a top bits have been dropped.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of byte range . A byte can store values from -128 to 127 only.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) on primitive datatypes :

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
>   It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

To respond your question : **How to Set greater than 127 int byte variable in java ?**

*The best way to represent an unsigned byte is to use a **signed integer***, because the Java VM represents bytes as 32 bits, you're not saving anything by using a byte.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the effect of a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3): casting the integer literal `128` to a `byte` results all all but the last byte being thrown out. The last byte of an integer has value `10000000`, which when interpreted in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) *as a one-byte value* comes out to `-128`.

In contrast, the same value interpreted as a four-byte value filled with zeroes on the left, i.e. `00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000`, equals `128`.

Answer (score 0):

Because one byte can hold upto -128 to 127 only, when you transform a int which is 
more than 127 or less than -127, the java compiler makes the change automatically.
In fact, the following statement

```
byte number_2 =  (byte) 128;
```

has been changed to

```
byte number_2 =  (byte) -128;
```

Once you check out the bytecode using javap, you will find it.