# Why for goes to infinite loop?

Tags: java

When I start my code

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

I get infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/3975838/1638718

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because byte value starts to overflow after its max value i.e. `127`.

The value of `i` will go up to `127` and then will overflow to `-128` and then increment back to 127. This process will therefore never satisfy your for loop termination condition, and thus loop forever.

Comment: after 127 it will wrap to -128 and count all the way up to 127 again.  All of the possible values are less than 1000 so it won't ever exit

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of a byte is less than 1000.

Comment: I know, the size of `byte` is [-128 to 127]. But it doesn't explain the infinite loop.

Comment: How is the loop supposed to end if it is not possible for i >= 1000 to be true?

Comment: yes, right. I see now.